# Google App Invites Unity3D Plugin Json File Location

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am trying to integrate Google Invites in Unity 3D Android, there is no official plugin for this but I can create one. The problem is I am not sure where to place the json file in Unity Project.

In Android Studio it needs to be placed in app/ or mobile/ directory.

Can any one help me and tell me where to place the google-services.json file in Unity Android project.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this json something that needs to be modified at runtime? or is it some persistent data store that doesn't change? I think you need to give us a bit more info about the json file in question.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the `google-services.json` file into the `Assets` folder. It's the same folder used by other Google plugins, like Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-config-file)